# Android compileSdkVersion No code hint for Android Studio xml files after upgrading to 33

Tags: android

Android compileSdkVersion No code hint for Android Studio xml files after upgrading to 33

I tried everything Chatgpt had to offer and it worked

Comment: Hints have nothing to do with sdk 33 it must still come. Try clean project then rebuild the project

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.